# Jack Henry: How do I get good data back from Account Post Memo Search?

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

I am unable to get good data back for Account Post Memo Search for accounts that have transfers that show up in Transfer Search. From what I understand, these transfers should show up in Account Post Memo Search as well. Is that the case?

I am sending the following in the request body:

```
<AcctMemoPostSrch xmlns="http://jackhenry.com/jxchange/TPG/2008">
    <SrchMsgRqHdr>
        {{jxchange header redacted}}
        <MaxRec>50</MaxRec>
        <Cursor/>
        <Ver_1/>
        <Ver_2/>
        <Ver_3/>
    </SrchMsgRqHdr>
    <InAcctId>
        <AcctId>8004723</AcctId>
        <AcctType>D</AcctType>
        <Ver_1/>
    </InAcctId>
    <ChkNumStart/>
    <ChkNumEnd/>
    <StartDt>2020-12-07</StartDt>
    <EndDt>2023-07-30</EndDt>
    <LowAmt>0.0</LowAmt>
    <HighAmt>2000.0</HighAmt>
    <SrtMthd/>
    <TrnType/>
    <EFTOnly/>
    <Custom/>
    <Ver_1/>
    <XferKey/>
    <Ver_2/>
    <IncXtendElemArray>
        <IncXtendElemInfo>
            <XtendElem/>
            <Ver_1/>
        </IncXtendElemInfo>
    </IncXtendElemArray>
    <Ver_3/>
    <TrnRcptId/>
    <Ver_4/>
</AcctMemoPostSrch>
```

For every account I try, I get the following back:

```
<MsgRec>
    <ErrCode>49</ErrCode>
    <ErrCat>Warning</ErrCat>
    <ErrDesc>No Records Match Selection Criteria</ErrDesc>
    <ErrElem>InAcctId.AcctId InAcctId.AcctType</ErrElem>
    <ErrElemVal>8004723/D</ErrElemVal>
    <ErrLoc>DDTRN2SRCH</ErrLoc>
    <Ver_1></Ver_1>
</MsgRec>
```

Is there anything wrong with the request body? is my assumption that transfers should show up here incorrect? Is it possible that this call is not setup to work in the environment I'm working in? If so, what do we need to do to get it working?

I tried sending the request shared above to Jack Henry's Account Post Memo Search service. I expected to get back results on memo posts for the account provided, including data on transfers that have been established in Transfer Add calls. Instead I got back the response I shared above instead.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Consider adding one or two more relevant tags for better visibility. jackhenry-jxchange has very few followers.

Comment: Try with 8318033-D

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your request. From the looks of your request, you're searching on deposit account 8004723 on transactions/transfers between 0 and 2000 dollars. It would seem that there were no transactions/transfers that met that criteria at the time you ran the API.

The AcctMemoPostSrch service is designed to only search for transactions that are not yet hard-posted to the core. For example, a transaction or transfer that has taken place today, would show up in the response. Once End-of-Day processing has been completed, those transactions/transfers would no longer show up in the response on this service. At that point, you would need to use the AcctHistSrch API to get those transactions.

You can find additional documentation on the AcctHistSrch API here: https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/accthistsrch/

I have added a new transfer as of 8/8/2023, and adjusted the date on your request and am getting results on the response. Keep in mind that this response will only be applicable until the next EOD processing, which would occur tonight.

```
`<AcctMemoPostSrchResponse xmlns="http://jackhenry.com/jxchange/TPG/2008" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <SrchMsgRsHdr>
            <jXchangeHdr>
                <JxVer>*REDACTED*</JxVer>
                <AuditUsrId>*REDACTED*</AuditUsrId>
                <AuditWsId>*REDACTED*</AuditWsId>
                <AuthenUsrId></AuthenUsrId>
                <ConsumerName></ConsumerName>
                <ConsumerProd></ConsumerProd>
                <Ver_1></Ver_1>
                <jXLogTrackingId>*REDACTED*</jXLogTrackingId>
                <Ver_2></Ver_2>
                <InstRtId>*REDACTED*</InstRtId>
                <InstEnv>*REDACTED*</InstEnv>
                <Ver_3></Ver_3>
                <BusCorrelId>*REDACTED*</BusCorrelId>
                <Ver_4></Ver_4>
                <WorkflowCorrelId></WorkflowCorrelId>
                <Ver_5></Ver_5>
                <ValidConsmName>*REDACTED*</ValidConsmName>
                <ValidConsmProd>*REDACTED*</ValidConsmProd>
            </jXchangeHdr>
            <SentRec>1</SentRec>
            <MoreRec>false</MoreRec>
            <Cursor>0</Cursor>
            <TotRec>1</TotRec>
            <Ver_1></Ver_1>
        </SrchMsgRsHdr>
        <AcctMemoPostSrchRecArray>
            <AcctHistSrchRec>
                <DepHistSrchRec>
                    <DepAcctId>
                        <AcctId>8004723</AcctId>
                        <AcctType>D</AcctType>
                        <Ver_1></Ver_1>
                    </DepAcctId>
                    <TrnCodeCode>641</TrnCodeCode>
                    <TrnCodeDesc>Transfer from DDA</TrnCodeDesc>
                    <PostDt>2023-08-08</PostDt>
                    <Amt>11.11</Amt>
                    <SrcCodeDesc>HOME/DIGITAL BANKING</SrcCodeDesc>
                    <TrnType>C</TrnType>
                    <AffCode>B</AffCode>
                    <ImgNum>0</ImgNum>
                    <EffDt>2023-08-08</EffDt>
                    <ChkNum>0</ChkNum>
                    <MemoPost>
                        <MemoPost>Y</MemoPost>
                        <MemoPostRmkArray>
                            <MemoPostRmkInfo>
                                <MemoPostRmk>Comp A X1001 to Comp B X1002</MemoPostRmk>
                                <Ver_1></Ver_1>
                            </MemoPostRmkInfo>
                            <MemoPostRmkInfo>
                                <MemoPostRmk>Test line 3Test line 4</MemoPostRmk>
                                <Ver_1></Ver_1>
                            </MemoPostRmkInfo>
                        </MemoPostRmkArray>
                        <MemoTimeEntry>11:36:39-05:00</MemoTimeEntry>
                        <Ver_1></Ver_1>
                    </MemoPost>
                    <Ver_1></Ver_1>
                    <Ver_2></Ver_2>
                    <Ver_3></Ver_3>
                    <ODPrvlgTrnType>false</ODPrvlgTrnType>
                    <Ver_4></Ver_4>
                    <Ver_5></Ver_5>
                    <Ver_6></Ver_6>
                    <Ver_7></Ver_7>
                    <TrnRcptId>JX66FQZ4YJ</TrnRcptId>
                    <Ver_8></Ver_8>
                    <TrnHistBalAmt>.00</TrnHistBalAmt>
                    <Ver_9></Ver_9>
                    <Ver_10></Ver_10>
                    <HistRecId>8004723D,451382</HistRecId>
                    <Ver_11></Ver_11>
                </DepHistSrchRec>
                <Ver_1></Ver_1>
            </AcctHistSrchRec>
        </AcctMemoPostSrchRecArray>
        <Ver_1></Ver_1>
    </AcctMemoPostSrchResponse>`
```